# css display property changed via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a little problem with the css display property.

I have the following pieces of code:

```
<input type="text" name="extra" value="" id="i1" style="display:block">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeVisibility(el){
            if(el.style.display="block"){el.style.display="none";}
            else { el.style.display="block";}                 
        }
</script>
```

problem is it doesn't work :) it starts out being displayed as a block and changing to none, but whenever I try calling the method again it doesn't change back to block?

Also when I try to view the page source when the field is no longer visible it is still set to "block" ?

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: about your second problem, if you view page source, you see the original source ( not modified ), you can use developer tools of the browser to see its current state ( F12 for IE/Chrome, Firebug for Firefox )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the equality operator is `==`, not `=`.

You are forever assigning it by `style.display="block"` so add another `=` to change the operation from assignment to equality.

Comment: wow, well s'pose that's what happens sometimes when you write in notepad :) thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

change your if statement to use == and not =.  That may be your problem.  Your if statement is always coming back as true, so it is always setting the display to none.